# Alternative for jq

Tags: node.js, command-prompt, jq

I am running a script which requires the `jq` command. It looks something like this:-

```
devHubSfdxAuthUrl=$(sfdx force:org:display --verbose -u $DEV_HUB_USERNAME --json | **jq** -r .result.sfdxAuthUrl)
```

JQ is not installed in my PC. Actually I am working in a system in my office, having restricted access.

I searched for the possible solution to install JQ. I concluded that I need to install Chocolatey first, in order o install and use JQ. As my office network restricts the access to the link to download chocolatey, I need any alternative solution, that I could use in place of JQ.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is really on-topic, per the Help Centre: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: Assuming you have a WIndows PC, you're almost certain to have Powershell available. I would do a search to see if Powershell supports json parsing. Good luck.

Comment: If you're on Windows and you're working on unix scripts, maybe spin up a linux virtual machine and work there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous ways to install jq on a Windows machine, without using chocolatey. Start with the binaries available via https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Alternatively, you can use the ConvertFrom-Json command to convert any JSON text into a PowerShell object.